# maven adds dependency but eclipse does not see it

Tags: eclipse, maven

I've created a new project in maven like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

After that I use: `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

The problem is that when I add the project to my IDE, eclipse indicates errors. When I run it I get `classNotFound` for JUnit. In project properties I see that junit is added to build path

In project properties I see: `M2_REPO/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar`

But I cant use for example: `import junit.framework.Test;`

Why is that? To be honest, I have some major problems with dependency in maven and eclipse. Maven adds them correctly but eclipse doesn't see it correctly. It's not only the junit. What should I check/set?

Should I install some plugin to eclipse for maven support ?

**EDIT**

I thought again about everything. Of course the problem was small. M2_REPO was not recognize by Eclipse. I've added this variable and set it in od maven directory. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the m2eclipse plugin for eclipse

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html

I don't know if having the plugin would solve your problem, I used to do the command line before I started using m2elcipse, I never had the issue that you described

what version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: one of the newer. Yes I`m also using command line cause I want to learn it from the basics. Maybe it`s the eclipse cause maven works good. Only eclipse didn`t have the variable matched to path. Or maybe I shoul M2_REPO add as system path ?